# How to access another class within a class

Tags: php, static, instance

I have 3 `classes`. One handles the database accesses.

The other class handles `events`. Each event(an array) contains a string with a class name and one with a method name. (In this case, it always calls the third class)

Then it calls the third `class`, and the method that is written in the event-array. Here, the event gets processed and things happen.

Now I have two problems:

First: Let's say I have 20 events in the event-array. That means, the second class calls the third class 20 times. Thus, 20 instances of the third class are generated. Is it better to use `static` for all of the classes?

Second: The methods of the third class need to have access to the database. I could write a class-variable that creates a new database-instance of the database-class each time the third class is called. But again, if the class is called like 20 times, it automatically creates 20 instances of the database class. How can I do this in a better way?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what exactly you need, but I'd first bet on *Dependency Injection*. Also see [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: I think it is better to use class container for the third class within the second class on which that methods (events) should be called